# Display unordered list as a horizontal binary tree

Tags: javascript, css, list, binary-tree

I have a binary tree in unordered list that looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li>1
    <ul> 
        <li>2
            <ul> 
                <li>4
                    <ul> 
                        <li>8</li> 
                        <li>--</li>
                    </ul> 
                </li> 
                <li>5</li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li>3
            <ul> 
                <li>6</li> 
                <li>7</li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
    </ul> 
</li>
```

Where -- is a empty space (to differ left/right child).

It displays as a classic unordered list. But that's hard to read and navigate through. I need a horizontal tree that looks like this:

http://www.knowledgerush.com/wiki_image/d/df/Binary_tree.png

It can be with or without the lines between the nodes.

**My question is - can this be done via html/css alone or do I need to use javascript for this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a great idea, but I see it very difficult to achieve.

- Lines vary in angle, so forget about doing it without some special logic (not achievable through HTML/CSS alone)
- Child nodes seem to occupy the same vertical space as other parent nodes (see for example nodes 5 and 7), while others don't (see nodes 4 and 5). That's also some special ordering.

Anyway, you *try* to set each LI to float left and have a width of 50%, so each new level will be narrower and narrower - haven't tried yet.

Also, you might find this plugin interesting, although it doesn't use ULs but DIVs and uses jQuery: http://www.ajaxupdates.com/jquery-binary-tree-plugin/

Comment: I tried the plugin - it's completely useless, it just displays it in order of the divs without any logic. I'll try the float and width of 50% ... if it doesnt work, I'll have to write something in javascript

Comment: okay, the 50% and float works ... however after 4-6 levels the width becomes very narrow ... so I may have to use quite big page (or rather a containing div with overflow:scrollable)

Comment: Yeah, available space will be reduced exponentially... On the other hand, if you need plenty of space consider making that available as an image instead, preprocessing it server-side. Or maybe even a PDF. Having a huge wide page isn't great for users with resolution @ 1024x768 :)

Comment: Yeah, pre-processing might be the best idea ... I need this mainly for users to see reports of their mlm downline - so some extra processing time won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

I did something very similar to this a while back, and examined the various options available. I wanted to be able to update the diagram in real time on an AJAX page, and ended up generating and modifying a [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) graphic with Javascript code. Firefox handled the resulting page extremely well and responsively, and I wasn't that worried that IE didn't cope with it at all.

Since then, we have had more developments with [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) and in particular the new [canvas tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_%28HTML_element%29). This sounds to be ideal for this sort of thing, and might be worth an experiment.

Good luck!

Comment: yes, I've been dying to try HTML5 and canvas tag - however I need this to work in every browser on every machine so ...